# How can I left join on a field that is made up of a comma separated list

Tags: sql, oracle, split, left-join

I'm trying to join a table on a list of comma separated values based on a field in a subquery that gets a hierarchy path. I have tried concatenating the relevant operators to the value and using an in it in the in clause. The concat is:

```
'('''||LTRIM(parent.path,''',')||''')'
```

when used as a select it returns something like this:

`('VALUE1','VALUE2','VALUE2')`.

However when I try to use it in the join:

```
left join table on id in ('('''||LTRIM(parent.path,''',')||''')')
```

it doesn't work.

If I substitute the results of the query ('VALUE1','VALUE2','VALUE2') with the formula I get the correct results.

Any help would be appreciated.

Whole query:

```
select '('''||LTRIM(parent.path,''',')||''')', dist.id, parent.*, opp.* 
from table1 opp
left join (
select connect_by_root(t1.id) as startpoint, connect_by_root(t1.parentid) as startparent,
t1.id as root_quote_id, SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(t1.id, ''',''') Path,LEVEL levels
from table2 t1
where connect_by_isleaf = 1
connect by prior t1.parentid = t1.id) parent on opp.distributor = parent.startpoint
left join table3 dist on dist.id in ('('''||LTRIM(parent.path,''',')||''')')
where startparent is not null
```

Comment: A string is a string, even if it contains commas and single quotes.  This is the wrong approach.  One idea is to use regular expressions instead.

Comment: *If I substitute the results of the query ('VALUE1','VALUE2','VALUE2') with the formula I get the correct results.* - the query you write gets compiled just like any other program (with identifiers, keywords, values) does. Noone has ever been able to say `SELECT * FROM t WHERE somecolumn IN '(my,list,of,values,in,a,string)'` - by the time the query is compiled into an executable form, it makes no more sense than being able to say `select '* from mytable'` as a valid query. The only way to make it valid is to build an entire string that is a query and EXEC it (which compiles and runs it)

Comment: This is a very frequently asked question - search for "comma-separated variable in IN list" or similar. But, in your case, the values to compare to don't begin life as a comma-separated list; YOU are assembling them together in that format. Don't do that; write the IN condition against the result of the hierarchical query directly, don't use the hierarchical path!

Comment: (Or.. do your join before you assemble your hierarchy)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the commenters that the best solution would be rewriting your query. If you provide some sample data and expected results, we can probably help with that.

However, if you don't have that luxury, an easy (and sloppy) solution to your problem is to treat your join as a substring search.

```
left join table3 dist on parent.path||''',''' like '%,'''||dist.id||''',%'
```

If you just used a single character as the sys_connect_by_path separator, this would be simpler:

```
select parent.path||',', dist.id, parent.*, opp.* 
from table1 opp
left join (
    select connect_by_root(t1.id) as startpoint, connect_by_root(t1.parentid) as startparent,
    t1.id as root_quote_id, SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(t1.id, ',') Path, LEVEL levels
    from table2 t1
    where connect_by_isleaf = 1
    connect by prior t1.parentid = t1.id) parent 
        on opp.distributor = parent.startpoint
left join table3 dist on parent.path||',' like '%,'||dist.id||',%'
where startparent is not null
```